# Find relation between these two subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> If$(x_n)$ be a sequence of real number such that subsequences $(x_{2n})$ and $(x_{3n})$ converges to K and L respectively.Then what is right-
>
> $\hspace{.5em}\begin{array}{rl} a. & (x_n) \hspace{.5em} always \hspace{.5em} converges \\b. & if \hspace{.5em} K =L \hspace{.5em}  then \hspace{.5em}  (x_n) \hspace{.5em} converges  \\ c. & (x_n) \hspace{.5em} maynot  \hspace{.5em} converge \hspace{.5em} but  \hspace{.5em} K=L  \\ d. & it 
> \hspace{.5em} is \hspace{.5em} possible \hspace{.5em} to \hspace{.5em} have \hspace{.5em} K \neq L \end{array}$

I think wrong options can be eliminated by choosing a proper sequence but how to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Under those hypothesis, the sequence may not converge, but $K=L$. That's so because $(x_{6n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a subsequence of both subsequences and therefore it converges to both $K$ and $L$.

However if you define$$x_n=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if $n$ is prime and }n>3\\0&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$then $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ devierges, but both sequences $(x_{2n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(x_{3n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converge to $0$.

Comment: but how to show that $(x_n)$ converges without knowing $x_{2n-1}$ converges

Comment: @EpsilonDelta I was wrong. Please read my edited answer.

Comment: how $(x_{3n})$ converges to 0,i think it doesnot converge

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Each $x_{3n}$ is equal to $0$, since no number of the form $3n$ is a primer number greater than $3$. Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{3n}=0$.

Comment: ohh! yes !!! sorry,it converges to 0

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong :

a) False.

b) False.

c) True.

d) $K=L.$

a)Consider the subsequence $x_p =p$ ; where $p$ is prime.

This subsequence does not converge, hence $x_n$ does not converge.

b) False, refer to argument in a).

c)True. $x_{2n}$ and $x_{3n}$ have a common subsequence $x_{6n}$, hence $K=L.$

d) $K=L$, argument in c).